# HTTP Status 404 – Not Found Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat

This is my code. I'm trying to add values to my table using JSP and MYSQL. Name of the table and database is correct.

```js
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import ="javax.sql.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Inserting Data from form</title>
</head>
<body>

      <h1> Insert a Record</h1>
      <form method="post" action="insertrecord.jsp">
      <table>
      <tr>
      <td>
       <input type="text" name="uname">
      </td>
      <td>
      <input type="password" name="upass">
      </td>
      <tr>
      <tr>
      <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value ="submit"></td>
      </tr>
      </table>
      </form>
 <%
 
 String sub = request.getParameter("submit");
 if(sub!=null)
 {
 String uname=request.getParameter("uname");
 String password = request.getParameter("upass");
 if(uname!=null && password!=null)
 {
  try
  {
      Connection con;
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
      con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo","root","");
      Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
      int i = stmt.executeUpdate("insert into user values ('"+uname+"','"+password+"')");
      out.println("Record Inserted Successfully");
      stmt.close();
      con.close();
  }
  catch(SQLException e)
  {
   out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
 }
 }
 %>  
   
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on submit. I'm getting this error:
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Type Status Report

Message /something/insertrecord.jsp

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.5

Comment: do you really want to insert data without checking it first ? This leads to SQL injections.

Comment: You also should create an account and give rights to the database it belongs. Using root is EVIL if you host several databases. I've investigated PROD servers hosting payment cards with such heresies. What was the result ?..

Comment: The error message speaks for itself: the target of the form does not exists. Correct the url.

Comment: I would recommended to use mvc. Do not mix up the code of view and databse.